# What is the difference between USB Mini A and Mini B?

Tags: usb, cable

I have a bunch of USB A to Mini B cables and a single USB A to Mini A cable. I have lost track of where they come from. The two types both look exactly the same with the USB A side having a white plate inside and the shape of the Mini plugs are the same too. So the only difference is that the Mini B plugs are black inside and the Mini A plug is white inside, like [the plugs shown here](http://www.penguin.cz/~utx/hardware/USB_Mini/), but my Mini A looks exactly like a Mini B except that it's white.

**What is the difference between my USB Mini B and Mini A cables?**  Do they have the same performance when plugged between my external hard drive and my computer? If not, which type would be better and how?

Should I trust the shape or the color? Because, again, my Mini A plug looks *exactly identical* to a Mini B plug except for its white-colored plate inside. So could it be that my Mini A is actually just a white-colored Mini B?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

USB specs defined two types of Devices at first. A devices, i.e. Hosts like your pc, and B Devices, i.e. Peripherals like a printer. At first, only standard size existed. Then mobile devices needing a smaller connecter, Mini-B was created. It is still for Peripherals only. Then OTG was added, creating the need for Mini-A (Miniature Host) and Mini-AB (Mixed, OTG device).

So Standard A Male to Mini B Male cables are for use from a Standard Host, to a Mini Peripheral. I.E. Your PC to a Cell phone.

Now, A Mini-A Male to Standard A FEMALE is allowed, as an adaptor, for OTG purposes. Mainly hooking up a standard device to a OTG host. Fairly common now. I have had tablets and phones that came with them in the box.
**A Mini-A Male to Standard A Male is non-standard as all heck.**

The color of the connector on the cable is also defined within USB Specs.

Notably, USB Mini is depreciated and has been replaced by USB Micro for years now.

https://web.archive.org/web/20161201042612/http://usb.org/developers/onthego/london/OTG_mechanical.pdf/ for an entire breakdown (simple to read) on the cable connector setup, as presented by the USB Implementers Forum.

Comment: Is an external hard drive with its own power source an A device or a B device? As it says on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Overview) "only the A-type socket provides power. There are cables with A-type connectors on both ends, but they should be used carefully." But I guess I still should use a standard A Male to Mini B Male between my powered PC and powered external HDD.  Is there *any* case with external HDDs where I should use standard A Male to Mini A male?

Comment: A Hard Drive with its own power source is a Self-Powered Device, just like Hubs. And no, not according to the USB specs. I mean, mini A and mini B cables are wired the same and the difference is just the physical shape, but its non-standard to have a mini-a connector on anything that is not OTG compatible.

Answer (score 2):

The difference only matters for On-The-Go applications, i.e. special cases when a device such as a printer or cellphone is acting in a "host" role rather than its usual "peripheral" role.  For your purpose, as long as the cable fits it will work and perform equally well to any other.

Comment: That is not correct - USB OTG requires the use of micro-A/B/AB plugs/receptacles. USB mini is not supported.

Comment: @RJR that is 100% wrong. OTG existed on USB Mini as well.

Comment: @cde not according to the specification: http://www.usb.org/developers/onthego/USB_OTG_and_EH_2-0.pdf - paragraph 3.1.1.

Comment: @RJR uhh... `Revision 1.3 December 5, 2006 Refer to the USB 2.0 specification and the Micro-USB supplement for all connector and cable assembly information and replace mini- connector references with micro-connector references`. Your blindly reading a document without regard to age, on a question that is age specific.

Comment: I stand corrected - I didn't realize anyone implemented OTG that long ago. Based on the OPs statement that "my Mini A looks exactly like a Mini B except that it's white." I would assume though that they're either all mini-A or all mini-B.

Answer (score 1):

See the picture below; Mini-A left, Mini-B right[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the plugs look exactly the same (shape - not color) then they are either both mini-A or both mini-B.
Mini A and Mini B are distinctly different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Mini_connectors

Note that a mini-AB receptacle accepts both mini-A and mini-B cables. So if your cables really have different plugs than they can be used interchangeably only if all your devices have mini-AB receptacles.

In summary: no difference. I suspect your mini-A cable is actually a USB Type-A to USB Mini-B cable.